# проблема с новым ноутбуком

Tags: ноутбук, dell

Купил новый ноутбук от компании Dell, такая проблема при включении кулеров издаётся какой-то звук неприятный,но короткий,это нормально или мне сдать по гарантии?Других нареканий у меня нету.

Comment: Многие системы воздушного охлаждения при влючении "продувают себя", кратковременно включив все пропеллеры на полню мощность. Типа, выдуть накопившуюся пыль, а потом уже работать в нормальном, "тихом" режиме. У Вас что то такое происходит?

Comment: То флопик инициализируется. ))